# Dodge not working when using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I saw a couple of posts on the similar problem but couldn't find a proper solution. Since the `count` in my data (reproducible example below) has duplicates, I need to print the overlapping points on the side of each other.  People are using `position_dodge` but somehow the example below is not working for me.

```
library('ggplot2')
myData = data.frame(split = c(rep('a',10), rep('b',10)), count = c(20,27,21,20,24,23,21,25,22,22,35,37,32,32,32,32,31,33,32,31))
p = ggplot(myData, aes(split, count)) + geom_point(aes(colour=split),  position=position_dodge(width=0.3))
p

#Getting the warning
ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need `position_jitter()` not dodge.

```
ggplot(myData, aes(split, count)) + geom_point(aes(colour=split), 
                                        position=position_jitter(width=0.3))
```

Other alternative is to use `geom_dotplot()`.

```
ggplot(myData, aes(split, count)) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill=split),binaxis = "y",stackdir="center")
```

[image]

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks. I also found some examples on `http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/geom_dotplot.html`

Answer (score 0):

Just mentioning that to specifically address the 'ymax not defined' message you could change your main ggplot aesthetic to this:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(split, count,ymax=max(count)*1.05))
```

and that would take care of it. Multiplying by 1.05 just to give some breathing space for annotation, should you want it.