# Position dodge with geom_point(), x=continuous, y=factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a function that can plot the loadings from many factor analyses at once, also when their variables do not overlap perfectly (or at all). It works fine, but sometimes factor loadings are identical across analyses which means that the points get plotted on top of each other.

```
library(pacman)
p_load(devtools, psych, stringr, plotflow)
source_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deleetdk/psych2/master/psych2.R")

loadings.plot2 = function(fa.objects, fa.names=NA) {
  fa.num = length(fa.objects) #number of fas

  #check names are correct or set automatically
  if (length(fa.names)==1 & is.na(fa.names)) {
    fa.names = str_c("fa.", 1:fa.num)
  }
  if (length(fa.names) != fa.num) {
    stop("Names vector does not match the number of factor analyses.")
  }

  #merge into df
  d = data.frame() #to merge into
  for (fa.idx in 1:fa.num) { #loop over fa objects
    loads = fa.objects[[fa.idx]]$loadings
    rnames = rownames(loads)
    loads = as.data.frame(as.vector(loads))
    rownames(loads) = rnames
    colnames(loads) = fa.names[fa.idx]

    d = merge.datasets(d, loads, 1)
  }

  #reshape to long form
  d2 = reshape(d,
               varying = 1:fa.num,
               direction="long",
               ids = rownames(d))
  d2$time = as.factor(d2$time)
  d2$id = as.factor(d2$id)
  colnames(d2)[2] = "fa"

  print(d2)

  #plot
  g = ggplot(reorder_by(id, ~ fa, d2), aes(x=fa, y=id, color=time, group=time)) +
      geom_point(position=position_dodge()) +
      xlab("Loading") + ylab("Indicator") +
      scale_color_discrete(name="Analysis",
                           labels=fa.names)

  return(g)
}

#Some example plots    
fa1 = fa(iris[-5])
fa2 = fa(iris[-c(1:50),-5])
fa3 = fa(ability)
fa4 = fa(ability[1:50,])

loadings.plot2(list(fa1,fa1,fa2))
```

[image]

Here I've plotted the same object twice just to show the effect. The plot has no red points because the green ones from `fa.2` are on top. Instead, I want them to be dodged on the y-axis. However, `position="dodge"` with various settings does not appear to make a difference.

However, `position="jitter"` works, but it is random, so sometimes it does not work well as well as makes the plot chaotic to look at.

[image]

How do I make the points dodged on the y-axis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, you can only dodge sideways, but there is a workaround. The trick is to flip your x and y, do the position_dodge, and then do a coord_flip().

```
  g = ggplot(data = reorder_by(id, ~ fa, d2), aes(x=id, y=fa, color=time, group=time)) +
    geom_point(position=position_dodge(width = .5)) +
    xlab("Loading") + ylab("Indicator") +
    scale_color_discrete(name="Analysis",
                         labels=fa.names) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: `reorder_by` is necessary to fix the order of the levels, otherwise they won't be in the right order (they will be in alphabetical because that's what ggplot2 likes). It is in the plotflow package (loaded by `p_load()`). In your answer, the order is reversed.

Good idea tho, I will try to see if I can find an acceptable solution with `coord_flip()`.

Comment: Yes, but you did so manually, so if I were to try to use your code on another dataset, it would (probably) not work well.

However, you seem to have made an error in the first line of the ggplot2 code. You have specified the `data` parameter twice. If one uses `g = ggplot(reorder_by(id, ~ fa, d2), aes(x=id, y=fa, color=time, group=time)) +` the plot works like it should with dodging as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281027/dodge-not-working-when-using-ggplot2)

In the linked post, the right answer states that one must use `position_jitter()` instead of `position_dodge()`. It has worked for me.